# git workflow for having production.cgi and production_test.cgi in the same directory

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I have my production code and my development/test code in the same directory on the live server. (I am not the boss, here.)  For example, the production file might be do_a_thing.cgi and the development file would be do_a_thing_test.cgi.

I'll be in branch dev, working on do_a_thing_test.cgi.
I'll be done testing/committing and I'm ready to promote my work to production.
Two things though:
One, perform a merge from dev to (master ?) that preserves the changes to do_a_thing_test.cgi as normal, but also promotes those changes to do_a_thing.cgi.
Two, don't actually write do_a_thing.cgi until later, when I git checkout (master ?).

The question is, in this environment, how can I produce a labelled revision for production, without actually editing existing production code.

Does this make me crazy?  Would subversion or other VCS be better for the environment I am in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So development code on dev branch and production code on master branch.

Since you just update `do_a_thing_test.cgi` on dev branch, so when you merge dev branch into master branch, `do_a_thing_test.cgi` and `do_a_thing.cgi` both keep the current version. If you want the master branch only has the update file but name `do_a_thing.cgi`, you can use `git rm do_a_thing.cgi` and `git mv do_a_thing_test.cgi do_a_thing.cgi`, and then commit the changes. But to make it easier and more clean, the file in dev branch can also be named `do_a_thing.cgi`, so that when you merge into master, git will compare the two files.

For other VCS, it’s also control versions almost, so git is enough.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Marina.  The problem is that my development space really is production.  If I gave the command, _git rm do_a_thing.cgi_, then the website would stop working, albeit only for as long as it took me to put another file in it's place, e.g. _git mv do_a_thing_test.cgi do_a_thing.cgi_.  But, I can't do that.

Comment: Yes, even development and production in the same space, but when you checkout to different branches, the working directories are different. So you can name `do_a_thing.cgi` both in master and dev branch.